# Tooling a person for amusement as opposed to practical gain

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose the following scenario.  Alice asks Bob a question which *seems* to be reasonable and for which she expects Bob to give an answer which is *superficially* a good answer, but which will expose Bob's innocence or naivety in a way that he himself will not understand but which will be amusing to those in a less innocent in-group to which Alice belongs.

Due to the dynamic of Bob's unwittingness and the somewhat covert nature of the maliciousness, I am tempted (as a native speaker) to say here:

> Alice is **tooling** Bob.

Or:

> ...  Before he learned the very counter-intuitive social dynamics of this environment, it was common for Bob to be **tooled** in such manners by Alice and her kind, who found him to be an amusing novelty.

However, "tooling" also strongly suggests that Alice is making some *use* of Bob to her own ends.  From this perspective, it doesn't seem like the *most* appropriate word, because she isn't really making any *practical* use of Bob, she's just doing it for amusement.  I suppose that amusement could be viewed as a use, but I'm concerned it could be amiss of the usual connotation.

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com) has no mention of the "using/messing with a person" sense of this word at all, and its sister site [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com) only covers the related noun, "person who allows himself to be used."  The latter does seem to suggest the need for an objective, though.

[wiktionary.org](http://en.wiktionary.org) does mention it, but the definition again seems to suggest there needs to be some objective.  Emphasis mine:

> To put down another person (possibly in a subtle, hidden way), and in that way to use him or her **to meet a goal**.

One might consider instead saying that "Alice is **teasing** Bob," but in *teasing*, the cruelty is usually overt -- i.e., Bob would *know* Alice was being mean.  I'm trying instead to suggest that Bob has no idea that Alice's question is insincere or that she regards his answer as foolish.

It would also be more or less correct to say that "Alice is **making fun of** Bob," but this likewise doesn't seem to express Bob's *obliviousness*, which is quite central to what I'm trying to express.

This is for literary use but in a somewhat informal style.  As the writer I am trying to criticize and pity Bob for his inability to see past the social norms that made his naive answer *seem* good.  Though Alice was slightly malicious, I'm not trying to be critical of her, instead taking the position of, "he was asking for it."

My question, then, is (i) whether this is a fitting use of "tooling," and (ii) whether there is a better transitive verb that expresses the particular dynamic described.  If it *is* a fitting use, showing existing examples of it being used in this way "in the wild" isn't essential but would make for the best answer.  Though I've tagged this as a single word request, it's possible that some brief, punchy expression might also work.

Comment: I've never heard the word *tooling* used in that manner. *Trolling* seems a better choice. (Or I might describe Bob as the unwitting butt of Alice's joke.)

Comment: Not at all familiar with "tooling" used in the context.

Comment: The wiktionary definition given seems more fitting for [negging](https://www.lexico.com/definition/negging) which doesn't seem to fit your use case. Alice is *using* Bob.

Comment: It seems strange that you will be taking sides with Alice, as if her actions have some merit, and not with Bob, her victim. How can naivety be *asking* for abusive treatment - isn't that "victim blaming" - or **victimising**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking, Baiting, Garden Path

Tooling is really slang (I think American English) and as it also can be slang for having sex it doesn't seem ideal for what you are trying to express.

How about 'subtly mocking' or 'covertly mocking'. Slyly mocking (sly means sneaky, underhand, mean). Or 'baiting' which means deliberately leading someone down a path in order to provoke something or make them look foolish.  The expression 'leading someone down the garden path' is also similar.

~Sounds like a bitch!

Mocking Definition
To ridicule or poke fun at someone.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mocking

Baiting
To deliberately lead someone on to make them look foolish.

Comment: I went with "sly mocking" (an edit changed the part of speech), which seems about the closest thing I could find to the intended connotations.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, for your comment! Glad it helped! ☺️✨

Answer (score 2):

**Tool** does indeed have a meaning of mistreating someone, though this is slang that many speakers may not know or commonly encounter.

*Green's Dictionary of Slang* (2011) has this entry under "*tool*, v.":

> **tool (around) (v.) (US campus)**
>
> to mistreat someone.
>
> 1967–8 Baker et al. CUSS 212: **Tooled** (around) Treated unfairly on an exam. 1988 Eble Campus Sl. Oct. 10: **tool** – ridicule […] Elizabeth **was tooled** by Doug because he never called her after she had professed her love for him.

In a similar vein to the second quote, the novel *[Going Vintage](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Going_Vintage/SYY6AwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22was%20tooled%20by%22)* by Lindsey Leavitt has this about a recent ex-boyfriend of the speaker:

> " [...] And I've already been there, done that, got that I **WAS TOOLED** BY JEREMY MCTOOLERSON T-shirt. And look what good came of it," I say.

That said, this may instead be a clipped instance of *tool off* or *tool out*, also from Green:

> **tool off (v.) (also tool out)**
>
> to leave, to go away; to abandon, to desert.

Then there are other senses of *tool*, like *tooling about* or *tooling around*, meaning to behave aimlessly or waste time (also Green).

So it is possible to use *tool* to suggest mistreatment on Alice's part to Bob, though it will sound unusual to many English speakers and may not hold all the nuances you want. (Mistreatment need not be deliberate, for instance.)

Comment: +1 for the research; unfortunately this all seems to miss the all-important covertness.  There probably isn't an exact word, but I ended up going with "sly mocking" from the other answer.